# Without knowing fluid density, can it be correctly determined by measuring both kinematic and dynamic viscosity directly?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, viscosity

Without knowing a fluid's density, can its density be correctly determined by measuring both kinematic and dynamic viscosity directly, and then dividing these values?

Can one determine cStokes and cPoise directly, then divide the cPoise by the cStoke and get density?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you can somehow measure the kinematic viscosity directly.  But the value may not be very accurate, since kinematic viscosity and dynamic viscosity are much more sensitive to temperature than density (at least for a liquid).  Also, if you are trying to back out the kinematic viscosity indirectly from measurements of pressure drop in turbulent flow, for example, the value you estimate for the kinematic viscosity may not be very accurate because the friction factor/Reynolds number correlation is only accurate to about 10%.  So, if you want to know the density, you should measure it directly, and, if you want to know the viscosity, you should measure the dynamic viscosity directly.

Comment: So, only absolute viscosity can be measured directly (without knowing density), and, devices that output kinematic viscosity measure absolute viscosity and density simultaneously to determine kinematic viscosity?  i.e. there are no devices that can measure kinematic viscosity directly without knowing density?

Comment: It's possible to measure kinematic viscosity indirectly using a dynamic test (time dependent variation), but, why bother, since dynamic viscosity can so easily be measured in a steady state test.

Comment: So a device like the Cannon-Fenske tube measures the kinematic viscosity, but does so indirectly, and it must be "Calibration against a standard liquid of known viscosity or against a second viscometer with a known constant must be made before use." - source: http://www.kimble-chase.com/advancedwebpage.aspx?cg=1052&cd=2&SKUTYPE=202&SKUFLD=SKU&DM=1250&WEBID=6177

Comment: I guess I misspoke.  The Cannon-Fenske uses Hagen-Poiseulle, but it uses gravity to drive the flow.  So it automatically delivers the kinematic viscosity.  But, if you are really serious about making viscosity measurements, I recommend against this device.  My understanding is that it is typically used to make spot measurements on process fluids to determine whether, at a particular point in the process, they are up to specs.  For serious viscosity measurements, more sophisticated and accurate devices are desirable.  This is particularly so for non-Newtonian fluids.

Comment: If is uses the Hagen-Poiseulle, wouldn't it need the dynamic viscosity value? Plus fluid density to convert the dynamic viscosity to kinematic?  I am basing this question off of the equation presented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Standard_fluid_dynamics_notation

Comment: Not if gravity is causing the flow.  It isn't the exact same thing as Hagen-Poiseulle, becuase the pressure is constant spatially in this test, but the weight of the water is balanced here by the viscous shear stress at the wall (rather than the viscous shear stress at the wall  balancing a pressure gradient in a horizontal pipe.  But the two situations are "kissin' cousins."  In Cannon-Fenske, the kinematic viscosity emerges as a parameter that can be measured (without knowing the density).  But, to then know the dynamic viscosity, you need to measure the density.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I wish I knew more about your motivation for all this.  It seems like we're making more of this than there actually is.

Comment: A friend of mine told me that dynamic viscosity requires density, going as far to say that only the kinematic viscosity can be measured directly and dynamic viscosity cannot be measured directly. When presenting him with information about directly-measuring dynamic viscosity viscometers he dismissed, saying, "No, the electronics in the high $ viscometers ALSO throw in the density measurement..using a similar principle as the Coriolis meters. Some SVM’s can be set to only measure rho, all you need is electricity LOL." I'm just trying to learn as I thought dynamic visc. can be directly measured

Comment: You're right and he's wrong.  Where did he get these crazy ideas from?